# Eclipse crashes after adding soapUI plugin

Tags: eclipse, soapui

I have installed SoapUI plugin to eclipse luna on ubuntu 12.04.
Installation was successful, but when I open soapUI perspective eclipse getting closed. I am not seeing any particular errors, got some info and warning like below.

WARN  [SoapUI] Missing folder [/home/dbpsysads/ext] for external libraries
INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] initialized soapui-settings from [/home/dbpsysads/soapui-settings.xml]

I followed installation from below link,
http://www.soapui.org/soapui-for-ide/eclipse/eclipse-plugin.html

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata folder to see if there are more detailed messages about the failure.

Comment: The SoapUI plugin is horrendously outdated and unfortunately no longer supported.

Comment: Oh is it? Thank you for the information. Will do a manual installation.